# navigation buttons shift when responsive menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is a navigation bar with a logo (home button) to the left and a call button and menu dropdown button to the right. Once the menu button is clicked and the dropdown menu is opened the call button moves to the right on top of the menu button and the entire navigation bar turns into just 1 button. What is causing this shift?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
   margin: 0px;
   background-color: #e6e6e6e6;
   color: #444;
   font: .9em Arial, sans-serif;
 }

 .topnav {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #185b9b;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }

 .topnav a {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
 }

 .topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #2672b2;
   color: white;
 }

 .active {
   background-color: #185b9b;
   color: white;
 }

 .topnav .icon {
   display: none;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
     display: none;
   }
   .topnav a.icon {
     float: right;
     display: block;
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav.responsive {
     position: relative;
   }
   .topnav.responsive .icon {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
   }
   .topnav.responsive a {
     float: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
   }
 }

 .main {
   padding: 16px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .wrapper {
   box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
   border-radius: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   background-color: white;
 }

 #one {
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   min-height: 130px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
 }

 #one img {
   max-height: 25px;
   max-width: 160px;
 }

 #two {
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 10px;
   min-height: 130px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 910px) {
   #one {
     float: none;
     margin-right: 10;
     width: auto;
     border: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Logo Name</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="#news">Download</a>
      
      
  
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  
  <a href="tel:800-922-0204" class="icon">
<i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
  </a>
    </div>

    <div class="main">

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, for the buttons overlapping each other, I saw this media query @media screen and (max-width: 600px) .topnav.responsive .icon { position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; } and both the bars and phone are in a link with the class icon, so they're both getting the same positioning which is why they're on top of each other.  As for the other stuff, not sure yet, but maybe this will help unwrap the mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bars icon and phone icon are both using the same class, so they are both being assigned the same positioning properties. Make them separate classes so they can keep their unique positions instead of overlapping.

```css
body {
     position: relative;
     height: 100vh;
     margin: 0px;
     background-color: #e6e6e6e6;
     color: #444;
     font: .9em Arial, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #185b9b;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
}

.topnav a {
     float: left;
     display: block;
     color: #f2f2f2;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
     background-color: #2672b2;
     color: white;
}

.active {
     background-color: #185b9b;
     color: white;
}

.topnav .iconBars, .topnav .iconPhone {
     display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
         display: none;
     }
     .topnav a.iconBars, .topnav a.iconPhone {
         float: right;
         display: block;
     }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .topnav.responsive {
         position: relative;
     }
     .topnav.responsive .iconBars {
         position: absolute;
         right: 0;
         top: 0;
     }
     .topnav.responsive .iconPhone {
         position: absolute;
         right: 47px;
         top: 0;
     }
     .topnav.responsive a {
         float: none;
         display: block;
         text-align: left;
     }
}

.main {
     padding: 16px;
     margin-top: 30px;
     height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
     box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
     border-radius: 5px;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     background-color: white;
}

#one {
     float: left;
     margin: 10px;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     min-height: 130px;
     width: 200px;
     height: 100%;
}

#one img {
     max-height: 25px;
     max-width: 160px;
}

#two {
     overflow: hidden;
     margin: 10px;
     min-height: 130px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 910px) {
     #one {
         float: none;
         margin-right: 10;
         width: auto;
         border: 0;
     }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
     </head>

     <body>

     <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
       <a href="#home" class="active">Logo Name</a>
       <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
       <a href="#news">Download</a>
       
       
   
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="iconBars" onclick="myFunction()">
     <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
   </a>
   
   <a href="tel:800-922-0204" class="iconPhone">
 <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
   </a>
     </div>

     <div class="main">

       <div class="wrapper">
         <div id="one">

           <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
         </div>
         <div id="two">
           <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
           <br>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
             posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
           <br>
           <p>
             <p>
               https://google.com/
             </p>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="wrapper">
         <div id="one">

           <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
         </div>
         <div id="two">
           <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
           <br>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
             posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
           <br>
           <p>
             <p>
               https://google.com/
             </p>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="wrapper">
         <div id="one">

           <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
         </div>
         <div id="two">
           <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
           <br>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
             posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
           <br>
           <p>
             <p>
               https://google.com/
             </p>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="wrapper">
         <div id="one">

           <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
         </div>
         <div id="two">
           <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
           <br>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
             posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
           <br>
           <p>
             <p>
               https://google.com/
             </p>
         </div>
       </div>

     </div>

     <script>
       function myFunction() {
         var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
         if (x.className === "topnav") {
           x.className += " responsive";
         } else {
           x.className = "topnav";
         }
       }

     </script>

   </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a media query with `position: absolute`

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav.responsive .icon {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
   }
```

This solution is without `position: absolute`

I removed the above from css, i give in `.topnav`

```
.topnav {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

And put both your menu links and icons inside a `div`. Take a look in the code above.

I hope it helps you.

```css
 body {
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
   margin: 0px;
   background-color: #e6e6e6e6;
   color: #444;
   font: .9em Arial, sans-serif;
 }

 .topnav {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #185b9b;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
     display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
 }

 .topnav a {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
 }

 .topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #2672b2;
   color: white;
 }

 .active {
   background-color: #185b9b;
   color: white;
 }

 .topnav .icon {
   display: none;
 }

.menu-icons {
  display: flex;
  height:48px;
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
     display: none;
   }
   .topnav a.icon {
     float: right;
     display: block;
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav.responsive {
     position: relative;
   }
   .topnav.responsive a {
     float: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
   }
 }

 .main {
   padding: 16px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .wrapper {
   box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
   border-radius: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   background-color: white;
 }

 #one {
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   min-height: 130px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
 }

 #one img {
   max-height: 25px;
   max-width: 160px;
 }

 #two {
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 10px;
   min-height: 130px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 910px) {
   #one {
     float: none;
     margin-right: 10;
     width: auto;
     border: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <div>
      <a href="#home" class="active">Logo Name</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="#news">Download</a>
      </div>
     <div class="menu-icons"> 
    <a href="tel:800-922-0204" class="icon">
<i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="main">

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">

          <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis
            posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
          <br>
          <p>
            <p>
              https://google.com/
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

`